# Repairing a multimeter

Tags: multimeter

I am attempting to repair my multimeter which hasn't worked since I tried to take an AC reading of an electrical item that blew a fuse and caused a loud pop on the source. Since this even the lcd displays incomplete characters and won't take readings. I opened it up and it looks as if the glass component(bottom of photo) may have blown.

[image: multimeter mainboard]

Would replacing this fix the unit? I know this items are cheap enough to throwaway but I'm curious to attempt a fix.

Comment: If that is a fuse and it looks burned out, you could replace it. No guarantee that is the only problem, though. What about the upper just left-of-center resistors? It may be the reflection/lighting that is distracting me, but it looks almost as though one or two of those resistors "don't look like the others." Look closer and tell us if those look okay to you.

Comment: _"Since this even the lcd displays incomplete characters..."_ - this suggests the meter chip is partially fried. I wouldn't bother trying to fix it.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. Please be aware that questions on repair of items are off-topic.

Answer (score 4):

There are a couple of clearly burnt resistors or capacitors above the black wire of the buzzer, surrounded by a scorched area. The "brains" of the multimeter (chip under the blob of black resin) are likely to have been destroyed by the same event. So no, replacing that glass thing won't fix it.

That multimeter has no input protection at all (I don't even see a cheap fuse in series with the current measurement shunt resistor), so I'd never use it on anything above 24 V or capable of delivering more than 20 A. Scratch that, I'd throw it in the trash and buy one that measures accurately and won't kill.

Answer (score 2):

If the LCD is displaying incomplete characters, and it is driven directly from the main chip (black blob) there is no hope.